# Approximating functions with Polynomials from Taylor Series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation, real-numbers

I wish to approximate the value of $e$ and show this is accurate to at least the sixth digit. I am wondering if in doing so I need to use the Taylor Series for $e^x$ about $1$ or does it suffice to use $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ with $x=1$.

From here I believe I then would need to solve $|R_n(x)|<|\frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}|=|\frac{3}{(n+1)!}|<.0000005$ which would work for $n=10$. Then just calculate $P_{10}(x)$. I have already shown that $e^x<3$ which is how I bounded the remainder function.

Does this work or should I redo the process with the Taylor Series centered about the value which we wish to approximate?

Comment: You just showed that the remainder, i.e. the difference between the computed value and the true value is within tolerance. What more do you want ?

Comment: I was just wondering if I should have used the Taylor Series centered around $x=1$ to estimate it at that value and a reasoning for why

Comment: What is the rationale of recomputing the value when you have proven that you have the right one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. It was possible, because you know the values of $e^x$ and its derivatives, at 0 (they all equal 1). If you centre the series at 1 instead, then you need to know the value of $e^x$ at $x=1$, which is the very thing that you hope to approximate !

Comment: ah perfect thank you so much! So in general, can we approximate $e^x$ with the Taylor Series at $x=0$ for any value of $x$ within the interval of convergence

Comment: Yes. And I have good news for you: The radius of convergence is infinite, in this case !

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up! Super convenient that the terms go to zero quickly too

Comment: You're most welcome ! And, I know, right ?!